# C reference gone after for loop

Tags: c, loops, pointers, for-loop

i got a problem with my C code.

```
int split(char* source, char*** target, char* splitChar) {
    int i;
    int currentLength;
    int splitCharPosition;
    char* currentSubstring = source;
    int splitCount = charcount(source, splitChar) + 1;

    *target = (char**) malloc(splitCount * sizeof(char**));
    for(i=0;i<splitCount;i++) {
        splitCharPosition = indexOf(currentSubstring, splitChar);
        substring(currentSubstring, target[i], 0, splitCharPosition);
        currentLength = strlen(currentSubstring);
        substring(currentSubstring, &currentSubstring, splitCharPosition + 1, curr  entLength-splitCharPosition);
    }
    return splitCount;
}
```

The problem is that if I use the Debugger, the pointer to splitChar is set to 0x0 after the first run of the for loop.
Does anybody know why it is set to 0x0?

EDIT:

```
int indexOf(char* source, char* template) {
int i;
int j;
int index;
for (i = 0; source[i]; i++) {
    index = i;
    for (j = 0; template[j]; j++) {
        if (source[i + j] != template[j]) {
            index = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index != -1) {
        return index;
    }
}
return -1;
}
```

EDIT2:

```
int charcount(char* source, const char* countChar) {
int i;
int count = 0;
for(i=0;source[i];i++) {
    if(source[i] == countChar[0]) {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

EDIT3:

```
char* substring(char* source, char** target, int start, int length) {
    *target = (char*) malloc(length + 1);
    strncpy(*target, source + start, length);
    target[length] = '\0';
    return *target;
}
```

EDIT4:
I just noticed that if I add

```
char* sndfpgjps = splitChar;
```

to my split() code it does not delete the reference. Anyone know why?

Comment: You get an upvote for mentioning that you used a debugger before coming here to post your question.

Comment: What does indexOf() do?

Comment: This might just be me, but I feel like this code is overly complicated for what it is trying to achieve.

Comment: indexOf() checks if the splitChar is in the currentSubstring.

Comment: Do you mean that `splitChar` is set to `NULL`? Or that the character `splitChar` points to is 0? (You said the pointer to splitChar, but where is anything pointing to splitChar?)

Comment: The only place you touch splitChar is in `indexOf()`, so look there first (or show the function)

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: Before it points to 0xbffff36b and after the first run it points to 0x0.

Comment: `splitChar` is also passed to `charcount()`, so show us that function too.

Comment: Access by the `target` is probably protrudes.

Comment: `char*** target` is a *very* bad smell IMO.

Comment: It is planned that I am also able to split on Strings. I want to implement that later. First I had wanted to get it with a single char to work.

Comment: [Three Star Programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)?  Beware!

Comment: @lutzb : Understood. Maybe the compiler has worked out (as I did) that the 'pointer' isn't actually needed as a pointer, and has reused the register for something else after the first access. Try it with optimizations disabled.

Comment: You might want to think about using: `int indexOf(const char *haystack, const char *needle) { const char *pos = strstr(haystack, needle); if (pos != 0) return (pos - haystack); else return -1; }` which is more succinct and uses standard functions (and handles multi-character strings as easily as single-character ones).  I doubt this affects the bug, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some reservations about the code, but this works cleanly under `valgrind` (no leaks, no abuse).  I've left the sub-functions largely unchanged except that constant strings are marked constant.  The code in `split()` has been simplified.  As I noted in a comment, I suggest writing the main `split()` function so that you have a local `char **string_list;` which you allocate and fill. Then, when you're about to return, you assign `*target = string_list;`. This will make it easier for you to understand what's going on. Triple indirection is nasty. You can justify it here (just), but minimize the time you spend working with triple pointers.  The revision adopts that strategy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int split(const char *source, char ***target, const char *splitStr);

static int
indexOf(const char *source, const char *template)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int index;
    for (i = 0; source[i]; i++)
    {
        index = i;
        for (j = 0; template[j]; j++)
        {
            if (source[i + j] != template[j])
            {
                index = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index != -1)
            return index;
    }
    return -1;
}

static int
charcount(const char *source, const char *countChar)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; source[i]; i++)
    {
        if (source[i] == countChar[0])
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

static char *
substring(const char *source, int start, int length)
{
    char *target = (char *)malloc(length + 1);
    if (target != 0)
    {
        memmove(target, source + start, length);
        target[length] = '\0';
    }
    return target;
}

int
split(const char *source, char ***target, const char *splitStr)
{
    int    splitCount = charcount(source, splitStr) + 1;
    char **result = (char **)malloc(splitCount * sizeof(*result));

    if (result == 0)
        return -1;

    int    splitLength = strlen(splitStr);
    char **next = result;
    const char *currentSubstring = source;

    for (int i = 0; i < splitCount; i++)
    {
        int splitCharPosition = indexOf(currentSubstring, splitStr);
        if (splitCharPosition < 0)
            break;
        *next++ = substring(currentSubstring, 0, splitCharPosition);
        currentSubstring += splitCharPosition + splitLength;
    }
    *next++ = substring(currentSubstring, 0, strlen(currentSubstring));
    *target = result;
    return (next - result);     /* Actual number of strings */
}

static void print_list(int nstrings, char **strings)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nstrings; i++)
    {
        if (strings[i] != 0)
            printf("%d: <<%s>>\n", i, strings[i]);
    }
}

static void free_list(int nstrings, char **strings)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nstrings; i++)
        free(strings[i]);
    free(strings);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char source[] = "This is a string; it is really!";
    char **strings;
    int nstrings;

    nstrings = split(source, &strings, " ");
    printf("Splitting: <<%s>> on <<%s>>\n", source, " ");
    print_list(nstrings, strings);
    free_list(nstrings, strings);

    nstrings = split(source, &strings, "is");
    printf("Splitting: <<%s>> on <<%s>>\n", source, "is");
    print_list(nstrings, strings);
    free_list(nstrings, strings);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that in the second example, `charcount()` returns 6 but there are only 4 strings.  This caused a late adjustment to the source code.  (You could `realloc()` the `result` so it is exactly the right size, but it probably isn't worth worrying about unless the discrepancy is really marked — say 'more than 10 entries'.)  The error handling is not perfect; it doesn't access invalid memory after failure to allocate, but it doesn't stop trying to allocate, either.  Nor does it report failures to allocate individual strings — it does for failure to allocate the array of pointers.

I'd probably avoid the triple pointer by creating a structure:

```
typedef struct StringList
{
    size_t     nstrings;
    char     **strings;
} StringList;
```

You can then pass a pointer to one of these into `split()`, and into the utility functions such as `free_list()` and `print_list()`.  The `free_list()` function would then modify the structure so that both elements are zeroed after the data pointed at by the structure is freed.

I'd also be tempted to use a different implementation of `indexOf()`:

```
int indexOf(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    const char *pos = strstr(haystack, needle);
    if (pos != 0)
        return (pos - haystack);
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line:-

```
    substring(currentSubstring, &currentSubstring, splitCharPosition + 1, curr  entLength-splitCharPosition);
```

... will cause a memory leak, as well as being incredibly inefficient. The old substring is left dangling. and never freed.

It would be much better to write

```
currentSubString += splitCharPosition + 1;
```

I don't think that's *the* problem, but it's *a* problem.

Also, as you're using C library functions like `strlen()`, why aren't you using `strtok` or better yet, `strtok_r`?

Comment: Is there a C library function that can split the given string on strings?

Comment: There's no function in the standard C library that will split a string based on a delimiter string such as you want.  The nearest approach is the `strtok()` function, but it splits on any of a selection of single characters, not on a character string (and has a number of other problems — avoid `strtok()` when you can; use `strtok_r()` or `strtok_s()` when you can't). One reason is that the standard C library avoids memory allocation almost everywhere (except `malloc()`, `realloc()`, `calloc()` and `free()`, of course).  TR 24731-2 would change that; it was not adopted into C2011.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what substring does, nor what signature it has, but in the line

```
substring(currentSubstring, target[i], 0, splitCharPosition);
```

target[i] is only defined for i==0. I believe you wanted to write

```
substring(currentSubstring, (*target)[i], 0, splitCharPosition);
```

Comment: You're right. That was what i had wanted to do. But unfortunately this does not solve my problem.

Comment: This is a correct diagnosis of one problem. I suggest writing the main `split()` function so that you have a local `char **string_list;` which you allocate and fill.  Then, when you're about to return, you assign `*target = string_list;`.  This will make it easier for you to understand what's going on.  Triple indirection is nasty.  You can justify it here (just), but minimize the time you spend working with triple pointers as shown.

Answer (score 0):

See if your debugger also supports data breakpoints, i.e. break if some place in memory is modified. Then place one at the actual address of splitChar, and another at the address it points to. (Since you didn't specify whether the pointer is null or points to nil.) See where it breaks. It may be that it is a completely unrelated place; that would indicate a buffer overflow.

Also, you could make at least splitChar a pointer to const. You don't actually want to modify it, right? Better idea, make it a char, not a pointer, since its name suggests that there is only one character on which you split, not a string.

Comment: Tried it with const, but it still does not work. The name might be chosen wrong, I also want to split on a String.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to `substring` does not look correct:

```
substring(currentSubstring, target[i], 0, splitCharPosition);
```

I suspect it should be something like the following where it indexes the actual memory that was allocated:

```
substring(currentSubstring, &((*target)[i]), 0, splitCharPosition);
```

You first need to get the value that target points at (`*target`) and then index off of that and pass the address of that array location.

Comment: You're right. That was what i had wanted to do. But unfortunately this does not solve my problem.